# Entity Framework show multiple the same row

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, view, entity-framework-4

This is weird, I am using an ASP.NET MVC application and Entity Framework to map a view from my database.

I don't know why but the query returns the same rows (5 rows 2 times each) multiple times, while in the database the view show me 10 distinct rows.

Don't understand what is going on.

Please help!

Comment: Share your code please.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known issue with views. Since a view (contrary to an actual table) in SQL Server doesn't have a defined primary key, EF will use **all non-nullable** columns as the primary key. These might be strings or other datatypes - and they might just really not make up a "good" primary key.

Now when EF reads the data, it comes across the first row in question, reads it into the dataset, and determines what the "substitute primary key" for that row is. When it then reads the next row from the database view, **if the non-nullable columns** are all the same, EF will interpret this as "this is the same row again" and it will **NOT** actually store the values from the database view, but it'll just use the row that it had just read before - since the **primary key** is the same, that's a valid approach.

How to solve this?

1. you can either explicitly define an EF-based primary key for your view entity that is in fact distinct for each row read
2. you can include the primary key columns of **all the tables** involved in the view - that way, the unique values from each table will be present in the view and thus will cause EF to properly recognize those distinct rows as being distinct rows.